# Laravel equivalent of sql datetime casting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table which consist of `ddate` and `time_start` column and I wanted to compare it to today.

In SQL Server, I can directly cast `ddate and timestart` to format my desired date and compare it to `GETDATE()`.

In my case, how do I compare the separate (`ddate` and `time_start`) to today?

**EDITED**
What I wanted is to concatenate it like '2020-06-01 11:23:00' and then compare it to today

Comment: Do you want to compare them in PHP or with query builder?

Comment: @shaedrich query builder. sorry forgot to mention this.

Comment: You mean ddate and time_start's type are all TIMESTAMP?

Comment: In that case you can do it exactly like you'd do in normal SQL. Depending on your logic, you might want to use a [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw)

Comment: @shaedrich Can you show an example?

Comment: Sure. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `whereRaw()` should be similar to what you're doing in plain SQL. If not, feel free to customize it.

```
DB::table('your_table')
    ->whereRaw('CONCAT(ddate, " ", time_start) = GETDATE()')
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm concerned about if I can directly concat the column. Thanks, man.

Comment: one last thing tho :), how can I convert `time_start` which is AM/PM format to 24 hour format. Normally one would use date('H:i:s', strtotime(time_start), but it gives me error.

Comment: That's because you're in SQL not PHP. It seems that MySQL can't really parse 12-hour format. Can't you store the time in 24-hour format and only output it in 12-hour format? I bet, that'd make it much easier.